# Change Windows user to an Administrator from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, administrator, standard-user

I had a single account on my Windows 10 laptop which I changed from an administrator to a standard account not knowing the consequences.

I tried booting Ubuntu (16.04) from a flash drive. But when I'm renaming `sethc.exe` file I get a popup showing "Error renaming file operation not supported". Please help me out of it and become the administrator user of the system.

Comment: Have you mounted the Windows drive in a mode that allows writing? By default most Linux boot drives will only mount the Windows partition in read-only mode.

Comment: I realize the duplicate has you use WinRE instead of Ubuntu but just because you want to use Ubuntu doesn't mean it's the correct approach to solve your problem.  Use a Windows installation ISO instead

Answer (score 1):

To get back administrator access -  Boot from the Ubuntu disk and install "chntpw". Run it from the command line (as root I imagine) and you can reset the admin permissions and password.  (See [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/reset-windows-passwords-with-the-help-of-linux/) guide)